# How can a border cause margins to collapse?

Tags: html, css, layout, border, margin

Please take a look at the following examples:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 740px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.leftSidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.mainContent {
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftSidebar">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <pre>.leftSidebar {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContent">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <pre>.mainContent {
  padding-right:200px;
  padding-left:200px;
}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 740px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.leftSidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.mainContent {
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftSidebar">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <pre>.leftSidebar {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContent">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <pre>.mainContent {
  padding-right:200px;
  padding-left:200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, a transparent border of `mainContent` changes the layout in a significant way.

Here is my idea about what's happening: For some reasons, the `border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` applied on `mainContent` causes the floating `leftSidebar`'s margin to collapse with the margin of `mainContent`, just like what a `display: inline-block` applied on `mainContent` would do.

However, I don't know the details. The [relevant part of CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) is too hard for me to understand. Can someone tell me why and how **exactly** the collapsing happens?

Answer (score 2):

The border isn't causing the margins of `.mainContent` to collapse with those of `.leftSidebar`. It's *preventing* the margins of its descendants from collapsing with itself (and therefore with `.wrapper`). That's why the top margin of `.mainContent > h2` is now aligned with that of `.leftSidebar > h2` — the reason the descendant margin of `.leftSidebar` similarly isn't collapsing with itself or `.wrapper` is because it's floating.

`.mainContent` and `.leftSidebar` are side by side, so there's no way their descendant margins could be considered adjoining, and so there's no way their descendant margins could collapse with one another.

Comment: I thought the reason why `mainContent` is aligned with `leftSidebar` is in some sense that the margins of the latter collapse with those of the former. Am I right?

Comment: Also, I found that the distance between the boxes and their parent(`.wrapper`) is reduced. If the collapsing is prevented, how can they become nearer?

Comment: What do you mean by "distance" and "nearer"? They're both inside their parent.

Comment: I apologize for not stating myself clearly. The `.leftSidebar` box seems to be pushed up after a transparent border is added, but as far as I know, margin collapsing can reduce the distance between `.leftSidebar` and the upper edge of `.wrapper`. So I think if collapsing is prevented, this distance should increase.

Comment: @sun qingyao: The .leftSidebar box remains in the same spot relative to .wrapper. It's .wrapper that's being moved up, because the top margin on .mainContent > h2 is no longer collapsing with .wrapper.

Comment: Got it! Yet another question: does this transparent-border approach function in the same way as the classic `display: inline-block;`/`display: table;` approach? In other words, is adding a transparent border functionally identical to establishing a new BFC? (I'm not very familiar with BFC, so I hope you can help me to clean things up…)

Comment: @sun qingyao: No; other than blocking margin collapse between a box and its descendants, the presence of a border has nothing in common with establishing a new BFC (and as you might have guessed, adding a border alone does not cause a box to establish a new BFC).

Comment: I might as well ask a new question about the specific differences between these two approaches(after my own research, of course). Thanks for your patient commenting!